# Retrieving cached oauth token with packages httr, twitteR, and streamR

Tags: r, twitter, oauth, httr

The only way I've found to get myself authenticated with the twitter API is the following:

```
library(twitteR)

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key = "a", 
                consumer_secret = "b", 
                access_token = "c", 
                access_secret = "d")
```

After running this, I can use all functions in twitteR just fine. However, I would also like to use the streamR package, which needs the token as an OAuth object:

```
filterStream("tweets.json", track = c("Obama", "Biden"), timeout = 20, oauth=my_oauth)
```

From what I gather, the setup_twitter_oauth function above is a wrapper around some httr functions to get my authorization token. This token is cached in my working directory as a file called ".httr-oauth". My question is: how do I load this file into R, such that I get an OAuth object that I can use with streamR?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `readRDS()`

```
readRDS('.httr-oauth')
$xxxx0x000xxxx00000x0xx0x000000xx


 request:   https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
 authorize: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate
 access:    https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token
 twitter
  key:    xxxxxxxxxx0xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  secret: 
 oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, user_id, screen_name
```

Access the environment in the list through `$long-alphanumeric-hash` and within that access `$credentials` and `$oauth_token`/`$oauth_token_secret`

Comment: Also, here is a great explanation regarding [how httr caches tokens](https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets/blob/master/internal-projects/13_how-httr-caches-tokens.md)

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack and doesn't directly retrieve the OAuth object from setup_twitter_oauth , but it works (adapted from http://www.datablog.sytpp.net/2014/04/scraping-twitter-with-r-a-how-to/).

Do the below once after you've setup your consumer_key and consumer_secret

```
    twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumer_key,
    consumerSecret=consumer_secret,
    requestURL="https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
    accessURL="https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
    authURL="http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize")
    twitCred$handshake()
    save(twitCred, file="credentials.RData")
```

When mixing TwitteR and streamR, use twitCred as the OAuth for streamR calls

```
    twitCred<- NULL
    load("credentials.RData")
```

Sample test streamR call to retrieve Tweets relating to football

```
    foo<- filterStream(file.name="",track =c("Football","NFL"),oauth=twitCred,timeout=30)
```