# Don't see .httr-oauth file after use of setup_twitter_oauth; want to use it to work with StreamR

Tags: r, twitter-oauth

I am trying to use setup_twitter_oauth authentication (from TwitteR package) to later on run StreamR search.

There is a related question in Stackoverflow about the same subject -

[Retrieving cached oauth token with packages httr, twitteR, and streamR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501775/retrieving-cached-oauth-token-with-packages-httr-twitter-and-streamr)

However my problem that I don't see .httr-oauth file in my working directory

The code I use to establish connection with Twitter is below

```
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token=NULL, access_secret=NULL)
```

(I use proper keys from my registered Twitter App)
It works I am getting [1] Using direct authentication message after execute it.

However there is no file called .httr-oaut in my work directory. Other hidden files are visible.

getOption("httr_oauth_cache") returns TRUE

What am I doing wrong and how can I get this file and use it in the future to establish connection with Twitter using StreamR, like for example in the command below

```
filterStream( file="tweets_rstats.json", track="rstats",
locations=c(-74,40,-73,41), timeout=600, oauth=my_oauth)
```

As I understood I need to pass it as oauth, so need in some way to save the token in my_oauth variable

Any help is appreciated